# How show multiplication of more than two matrix in just one line?

Tags: matrix

I have been going though some matrix multiplication problem and there I faced this kind of problem where I am trying to show the whole multiplication form in the next line of H.S.T.H.zero // MatrixForm but it's not working and I have to put all the matrix elements manually.

```
zero = {{1}, {0}} // MatrixForm
H = 1/sqrt[2] {{1, 1}, {1, -1}} // MatrixForm
S = {{1, 0}, {0, I}} // MatrixForm
T = {{1, 0}, {0 , E^(I Pi/4)}} // MatrixForm
H.S.T.H.zero // MatrixForm
```

the output it's showing --->
[image: The output that is showing]

But the output I want ----->
[image: Desired output]

If there any way to solve this please let me know! I would be very greatful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you like Latex, you could also use [Matex](http://szhorvat.net/pelican/latex-typesetting-in-mathematica.html) package.

```
<< MaTeX`
SetOptions[MaTeX, Magnification -> 2]

zero = {{1}, {0}}
H = 1/Sqrt[2] {{1, 1}, {1, -1}}
S = {{1, 0}, {0, I}}
T = {{1, 0}, {0, E^(I Pi/4)}}
result = H . S . T . H . zero
```

And now

```
Row[{MaTeX[MatrixForm@H],
  MaTeX[MatrixForm@S],
  MaTeX[MatrixForm@T],
  MaTeX[MatrixForm@H],
  MaTeX[MatrixForm@zero],
  MaTeX["="],
  MaTeX[MatrixForm@result]
  }]
```

[image]

If you want an explicit multiplication between them, (even though I do not think it is needed) you can do

```
Row[{MaTeX[MatrixForm@H],
  MaTeX["\\times"],
  MaTeX[MatrixForm@S],
  MaTeX["\\times"],
  MaTeX[MatrixForm@T],
  MaTeX["\\times"],
  MaTeX[MatrixForm@H],
  MaTeX["\\times"],
  MaTeX[MatrixForm@zero],
  MaTeX["="],
  MaTeX[MatrixForm@result]
  }]
```

[image]

But if you prefer dot for multiplication

```
Row[{MaTeX[MatrixForm@H],
  MaTeX["\\cdot"],
  MaTeX[MatrixForm@S],
  MaTeX["\\cdot"],
  MaTeX[MatrixForm@T],
  MaTeX["\\cdot"],
  MaTeX[MatrixForm@H],
  MaTeX["\\cdot"],
  MaTeX[MatrixForm@zero],
  MaTeX["="],
  MaTeX[MatrixForm@result]
  }]
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

```
$Version

(* "13.1.0 for Mac OS X x86 (64-bit) (June 16, 2022)" *)

Clear["Global`*"]
```

`sqrt` should be [`Sqrt`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Sqrt.html). All built-in functions start with a capital letter.

```
zero = {{1}, {0}};
H = 1/Sqrt[2] {{1, 1}, {1, -1}};
S = {{1, 0}, {0, I}};
T = {{1, 0}, {0, E^(I Pi/4)}};
(eqn = Inactivate[(H . S . T . H . zero), Dot] == 
    Simplify[H . S . T . H . zero]) /. mat_?MatrixQ :> MatrixForm[mat]
```

[image]

```
Activate@eqn

(* True *)
```